# Installing ODBC driver on Linux (Ubuntu) for Qt getting syntax error while running "make"

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, odbc, driver

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server database on ubuntu in Qt and need to install ODBC driver.
I did what document had told me to do [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html). And installed unixOBDC from [here](http://www.unixodbc.org/) into `/usr/local/unixODBC` then running these commands

```
cd ~/Qt5.7.0/5.7/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/odbc
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/unixODBC/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/unixODBC/lib -lodbc"
make
```

Which resulted in syntax error in couple of the sources [image]

This is what i get if i run my code at the moment

```
QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

What am i missing?

Edit:

```
    makeg++ -c -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wvla -Wdate-time -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_TSLIB -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.5.1 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/5.5.1/QtCore -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.5.1 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.5.1/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I.moc -I../../../../mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o .obj/qsql_odbc.o ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:193:44: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Q_DECLARE_SQLDRIVER_PRIVATE’ with no type [-fpermissive]
         Q_DECLARE_SQLDRIVER_PRIVATE(QODBCDriver)
                                                ^
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:193:44: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp: In constructor ‘QODBCResultPrivate::QODBCResultPrivate(QODBCResult*, const QODBCDriver*)’:
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:198:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlResultPrivate::QSqlResultPrivate(QODBCResult*&, const QODBCDriver*&)’
               hasSQLFetchScroll(true)
                                     ^
    In file included from ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:59:0:
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.5.1/QtSql/private/qsqlresult_p.h:67:5: note: candidate: QSqlResultPrivate::QSqlResultPrivate()
         QSqlResultPrivate()
         ^
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.5.1/QtSql/private/qsqlresult_p.h:67:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.5.1/QtSql/private/qsqlresult_p.h:63:20: note: candidate: QSqlResultPrivate::QSqlResultPrivate(const QSqlResultPrivate&)
     class Q_SQL_EXPORT QSqlResultPrivate
                        ^
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.5.1/QtSql/private/qsqlresult_p.h:63:20: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:200:30: error: ‘drv_d_func’ was not declared in this scope
             unicode = drv_d_func()->unicode;
                                  ^
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp: In member function ‘void* QODBCResultPrivate::dpEnv() const’:
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:209:49: error: ‘drv_d_func’ was not declared in this scope
         SQLHANDLE dpEnv() const { return drv_d_func() ? drv_d_func()->hEnv : 0;}
                                                     ^
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp: In member function ‘void* QODBCResultPrivate::dpDbc() const’:
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:210:49: error: ‘drv_d_func’ was not declared in this scope
         SQLHANDLE dpDbc() const { return drv_d_func() ? drv_d_func()->hDbc : 0;}
                                                     ^
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp: In member function ‘bool QODBCResultPrivate::isStmtHandleValid()’:
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:228:42: error: ‘drv_d_func’ was not declared in this scope
         return disconnectCount == drv_d_func()->disconnectCount;
                                              ^
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp: In member function ‘void QODBCResultPrivate::updateStmtHandleState()’:
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:233:34: error: ‘drv_d_func’ was not declared in this scope
         disconnectCount = drv_d_func()->disconnectCount;
                                      ^
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp: In constructor ‘QODBCResult::QODBCResult(const QODBCDriver*)’:
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:959:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘QSqlResult::QSqlResult(QODBCResultPrivate&)’
         : QSqlResult(*new QODBCResultPrivate(this, db))
                                                       ^
    In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/5.5.1/QtSql/private/qsqlresult_p.h:51:0,
                     from ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:59:
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:69:5: note: candidate: QSqlResult::QSqlResult(QSqlResultPrivate&, const QSqlDriver*)
         QSqlResult(QSqlResultPrivate &dd, const QSqlDriver *db);
         ^
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:69:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:68:14: note: candidate: QSqlResult::QSqlResult(const QSqlDriver*)
         explicit QSqlResult(const QSqlDriver * db);
                  ^
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtSql/qsqlresult.h:68:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘QODBCResultPrivate’ to ‘const QSqlDriver*’
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool QODBCResult::exec()’:
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:1464:36: error: ‘class QODBCResultPrivate’ has no member named ‘drv_d_func’
                     int precision = d->drv_d_func()->datetime_precision - 20; // (2
                                        ^
    ../../../sql/drivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp:1480:42: error: ‘class QODBCResultPrivate’ has no member named ‘drv_d_func’
                                           d->drv_d_func()->datetime_precision,
                                              ^
    Makefile:463: recipe for target '.obj/qsql_odbc.o' failed
    make: *** [.obj/qsql_odbc.o] Error 1
```

Comment: try with: sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc

Comment: That screencap is very hard to work with...  Much better if you can copy-and-paste the text into a `<pre>…</pre>` block here.

Comment: @TallTed edited..

Comment: Note that Ubuntu has pre-built packages for this, you can apt-get install libqt5sql5-odbc tdsodbc

Comment: @nos i have tried that but no success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be caused by using wrong version of qmake. Most probably its not same as you use in source code.

Comment: True.. i used the full path and it was compiled.. but still i had the same QODCB driver not loaded which i managed to get free but now i it says 
    "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found QODBC3: Unable to connect"

Comment: Looks like unixODBC can not load sql server backend library. My suggestion to check your ODBC connection first using unixODBC command line tools. To be sure that your unixODBC setup is correct and working.

Comment: i get this error while trying to connect both with isql and in Qt

[S1T00][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: i changed localhost\sqlexpress to localhost and the issue was solved